# Problemas con enlace html -> js

Tags: javascript, html, css

estaba programando un boton el cual al darle click aumentara un conteo ...

```js
"use strict";
let button = {
    clicks: 0,
    htmlRef: document.querySelector(".button"),
};

console.log(button);
```

```css
.button {
    padding: 30px;
    background-color: #0f0;
    border-radius: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 45%;
    top: 40%;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 20px #0a0;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
    cursor: pointer;
}

:root {
    background-color: #222;
}

.button:hover {
    transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Titulo de la pagina</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
        <div class="button">Click</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Cuando estaba precisamente programando la parte de tomar el elemento `.button` y cambiar su `innerHtml` con el `button.clicks`, he tenido varios problemas para tomar el elemento desde js ...

1- Cuando hago un `button = document.getElementsByClassName("button")[0]`, desde el navegador todo va bien sin embargo al hacerlo desde el editor, el navegador dice que el elemento es `null` ...

***1er caso***

[image]

***2do caso***

*Editor*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*Navegador en respuesta a main.js*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

***Conclusion:*** Basicamente me da una respuesta cuando hago el codigo desde el navegador, y otra cuando lo hago desde `nvim`, alguna idea de que esta pasando?

Comment: Coloca el script al final, antes de `</body>`, porque ahora se ejecuta antes de que el botón se agregue al HTML y no lo encuentra.

Comment: @Triby Genio ! muchas gracias

Answer (score 0):

Para garantizar que los elementos están listos (veo que no usas JQuery) puedes poner el contenido de tu script como parte del evento **DOMContentLoaded** para que tu main.js quede algo como:

```
"use strict";
let button = {}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  button = {
    clicks: 0,
    htmlRef: document.querySelector(".button"),
  };

  console.log(button);
});
```